# Crashlytics symbols upload fails with "GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I've been desperately trying to upload my game symbols to crashlytics (gradlew uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease) and consistently failing with:

```
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

What have I tried already... I'm making sure my deamon has lots of memory to play with:

```
-XX:MaxHeapSize=32g,-XX:MaxPermSize=4096m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx4g
```

also on build.gradle:

```
dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 2
        javaMaxHeapSize "16g"
    }
```

running the uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease with debug and callstack, shows:

```
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17101328384, Free: 1893560320}
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I've also deleted the gradle registry folders, but nothing worked so far.
Contacted Firebase support on monday, but also got no reply.

I'm using the following versions:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:17.0.0'
```

And this is working perfectly on another game I have.

Comment: having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Aparently it's a known issue by Firebase. I was recommended to downgrade the gradle plugin to version 1.27.0, but I still have the issue.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is a known issue, and the workaround is to be on the legacy SDK downgrading your Fabric build tools version to v1.28.0, or v1.27.0 as you mentioned. Although if you're still seeing this exact error when on these versions I would say that's still unexpected behavior, as this workaround has been known to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to downgrade but there is no documentation anymore on how to properly setup 1.27 version. And the new version of my game using 1.27 is not sending any crash information to the console.

This is what I did. On root build.grande included

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0'
```

then on the app build.gradle...

on the top:

```
io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.0
```

inside the android tag:

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut ...    androidNdkLibsOut .....
}
```

on the dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.1'
```

And on the Java, included this on the onCreate event:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());
```

with the imports:

```
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import com.crashlytics.android.ndk.CrashlyticsNdk;
```

What am I missing?